# Find the minimum value of $p$ so that the series diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was doing this particular series question:

Find the minimum value of $p$ for which the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1n^{27}+8)^{27}(1+27n^{29}+8n^{30})^p$$

is divergent.

How would I do this? My idea was the use the comparison test and then use that fact for large values of $n$, this behaves like:

$$n^{729}*n^{30p}$$ so we get $30p+729<1$.

Is that the right idea? Or is that not the right approach?

Comment: they ask for the minimum $p.$  This does have an answer, as $30p + 729=-1$ gives a divergent series, but no smaller $p$

Comment: It should be $ 729+30p<-1$ (minus one)

Comment: Why does it need to be a $-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term of the series is positive, So we can use limit comparison test.

but

$$u_n\sim 8^p n^{27\times 27}.n^{30p}\sim 8^p.n^{729+30p}$$
So, the series converges if $$-729-30p>1$$

or
$$p<\frac{-73}{3}$$